# Django: Can not get django-admin.py to run anything

Tags: django

System: Windows 7x64

Django v. 1.4

Python v. 3.2

First time working with Django or python and I am beating my head against the wall.  I have installed everything for Django according to the install instructions.  The only step I skipped was the 'optional' virtualenv installation.

I am attempting to run the tutorial on djangoproject.com and I can't get startproject to work.  Here is my issues.

When attempting to use 'django-admin.py startproject mysite' or even just 'django-admin.py help' functions I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python32\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in
>
> from django.core import management   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 54
>
> except ImportError,e:
>                    ^ 
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Where the ^ is pointing to the comma.

I have checked the permissions for the folder I am in and everything appears to be good there.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Django doesn't work with python 3. Refer to this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3

Comment: Django doesn't support Python 3.x

Comment: Yes Django 1.4 does not work with Python 3. I wasted a lot of time and now am installing python 2.7.3 :(

Comment: For what it's worth, I had a similar issue using Django 1.6 and Python 2.6.6, but it turned out to be a permissions issue -- some of the files in site-packages were not executable, so once I fixed that, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django doesn't work with Python 3 (yet).

Install 2.7 instead.

Comment: You are exactly right... Just found that out after hours of hunting.  They really need to make that bit of text more obvious on their page its kind of important.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2):

You might also stick to Python 3.X and get [django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/) that is currently in beta phase.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.3 offers experimental support. django-admin.py still won't run properly, but here's a workaround for you:

You can call the django-admin subcommands directly from your own python script.

```
from django.core import management    
management.call_command("startproject", "mysite")
```

Almost everything else should be done from the manage.py file it generates, which should work fine with:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

or whatever command you're looking for. You may also be using "python33" instead of python.

Answer (score 1):

General answer: that syntax line isn't valid in Python 3.2 (Django [doesn't work with Python 3 yet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3)). [Here's a list of the 2.x versions you can use with particular versions of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django).

Specific answer: According to [PEP-3110](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/), the syntax for exceptions changed from `except Exception, e` to `except Exception as e` in Python 3, which is why that error's showing up.